# Postgres No Index Only Scan On Delete?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query running in Postgres 9.3.9 where I want to delete some records from a temp table based on using an EXISTS clause that matches a specific partial index condition I created.  The following related query uses an Index Only Scan on this partial index (abbreviated as 'conditions' below):

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT l.id              
FROM temp_table l
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1                           
          FROM customers cx
          WHERE cx.id = l.customer_id
            AND ( conditions ));

                                          QUERY PLAN                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.42..252440.38 rows=43549 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on temp_table l  (cost=0.00..1277.98 rows=87098 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using customers__bad on customers cx  (cost=0.42..3.35     rows=1 width=4)
         Index Cond: (id = l.customer_id)
(4 rows)
```

Here is the actual delete query SQL.  This doesn't but I am convinced should use the same Index Only Scan as above, and I wonder if it's a bug in Postgres?  Notice the higher cost:

```
DELETE
  FROM temp_table l
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1
          FROM cnu.customers cx
          WHERE cx.id = l.customer_id
            AND ( conditions ));


                                           QUERY PLAN                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on temp_table l  (cost=0.42..495426.94 rows=43549 width=12)
   ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.42..495426.94 rows=43549 width=12)
         ->  Seq Scan on temp_table l  (cost=0.00..1277.98 rows=87098 width=10)
         ->  Index Scan using customers__bad on customers cx  (cost=0.42..6.67 rows=1 width=10)
               Index Cond: (id = l.customer_id)
(5 rows)
```

To show that it should be possible on delete to get the same plan, I had to do this, and it gave me the plan I wanted, and was twice as fast as the query above that uses an Index Scan instead of Index Only Scan:

```
WITH the_right_records AS
(SELECT l.id
FROM temp_table l
WHERE NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
          FROM cnu.customers cx
          WHERE cx.id = l.customer_id
            AND ( conditions ))

DELETE FROM temp_table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM the_right_records x
                  WHERE x.id = t.id);

                                              QUERY PLAN                                              
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on temp_table t  (cost=253855.72..256902.88 rows=43549 width=34)
   CTE the_right_records
     ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.42..252440.38 rows=43549 width=4)
           ->  Seq Scan on temp_table l  (cost=0.00..1277.98 rows=87098 width=8)
           ->  Index Only Scan using customers__bad on customers cx  (cost=0.42..3.35 rows=1 width=4)
                 Index Cond: (id = l.customer_id)
   ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=1415.34..4462.50 rows=43549 width=34)
         Hash Cond: (t.id = x.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on temp_table t  (cost=0.00..1277.98 rows=87098 width=10)
         ->  Hash  (cost=870.98..870.98 rows=43549 width=32)
               ->  CTE Scan on the_right_records x  (cost=0.00..870.98     rows=43549 width=32)
(11 rows)
```

I've noticed this same behavior in other examples.  So anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick glance: your second query (the one that doesn't use the index-only scan) says "WHERE EXISTS", whereas all of your other queries say "WHERE NOT EXISTS".

Comment: Same logic though `SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS` should be the same as `DELETE WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: Might be *the same logic*, but not the same statistics. "where swans are black" vs "where swans are not black"

Comment: Might be worth raising on pgsql-performance as a possible planner issue

Comment: Related answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219112/3684